# X-bar analysis of Copular verbs?

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees, x-bar-theory

Can someone help me with the analysis of copular or linking verbs in X-bar theory. What would be the position of subject in sentences like `"Mary is beautiful"`. Is "Mary" the theme of adjectival predicate "beautiful" or the theme of "be" verb is? See the X-bar trees.

[image: two potential trees for 'Mary is beautiful']

I guess it makes more sense for it to be the theme of adjective (Fig 2).

Comment: Riyaz, welcome to Linguistics SE! Unfortunately it was decided to rule out requests for syntax trees. However, you can edit your question to provide your own syntax tree, your take on it, and ask where you have doubts and/or to correct your try. :) Thank you.

Comment: @Alenanno, see if it is appropriate now. Let me know if you want me to add some more details. I have a deadline, so couldn't write much.

Comment: What framework are you using? It seems odd to me to require Mary to be a complement. Why does it have to have moved?

Comment: @curiousdannii I am interested in its analysis in GB. Spec of IP is not the default position of subjects, they move to that position to get case. My question is about the default position of NP subject Mary. I haven't seen much trees on these kind of simple sentences. If you guys could suggest me any reading, I will be happy with that.

Comment: @Riyaz Ahh, it's been a long time since I've looked at GB so I don't remember anything like this. Can't help sorry.

Comment: What about simple phrase structure analysis. Can you help with that?

Comment: I don't think this analysis can be correct. Note that "heavy smoker" is a perfectly well-formed NP with an AP modifier, but "Smoker is heavy" and "The smoker is heavy" are both bad. Movement of an NP to the exclusion of its modifier is also disallowed elsewhere in English, e.g. "What did Mary buy a red *t*?" (bad). I don't know what the standard GB analysis of copulars is -- look at Liliane Haegeman's GB theory textbook.

Comment: I based my analysis on copular raising verb constructions like "John is likely to go." In this sentence John is the Agent of the lower verb "Go" and has nothing to do with "is" thematically. In the case of "Mary is beautiful", Mary similarly has nothing to do with "is" thematically. So it can't be generated within the maximal projection of "is".

Comment: @Elliott I don't mean leaving adjective as a modifier and moving head noun to spec of IP. What I meant is max NP as a complement of a head Adjective moves to Spec of IP.

Comment: @Riyaz I don't think your example question is anywhere similar to "John is likely to go", so the comparison isn't valid. What do you mean by "thematically"? This is a small site with only a few regulars, most of which aren't generative grammarians I think. And you're not asking a simple question, but asking us to validate or refute your own analysis, which takes a bit more effort ;)

Comment: @curiousdannii "likely" is an adjective and takes a complement, though a clausal one. Thats the reason I am drawing parallels between beautiful (or any other adjective) and likely. Similar to likely, why can't other adjectives have complement positions which would explain the position of subjects in copular verb constructions. "I used the term thematically for theta roles assigned by a verb or any other predicate."